# Trouble learning PDEs

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations

My college has started teaching PDEs, and I must say, it's the worst math course I've taken so far. I believe this is because of the sluggish curriculum of my college rather than the difficulty of the subject itself. For one thing, I'm not taught any proofs whatsoever! All I'm ever taught are a set of algorithms for solving different types of PDEs. Initially, I thought this was because the theory concerned was difficult, but upon a bit of self-studying, I realized this was not the case at all! I wasn't taught the method of characteristics, using which one can solve any first order linear PDE, but I was able to understand how and why it worked by studying on my own! (though it did take a few hours to fully grasp it).

Now we're being taught non linear PDEs of different types, again without proofs or the theory of it! It's all about following a series of steps for obtaining the general solution, without rigorously justifying it! The worse part is, that I can't find any of these algorithms in most of the standard PDE texts. Upon searching a bit more, I found this to be an exact ditto of what I'm being taught, again without any rigor at all:-

http://sakshieducation.com/(S(2smf142r13zhkl45c1b3kc3a))/Engg/EnggAcademia/CommonSubjects/MM_Partial_Diffrential_Equations.pdf

I've searched high and low, but I can't find any books that even mentions these methods, let alone justify them! I can't stress enough on how frustrating this is for me, since I absolutely hate rote memorization without actually knowing the 'why' behind it.

Can anyone please tell me, or even point me to some resources that explain the methods mentioned in the above PDF (especially the nonlinear part) in detail with justification, as to why it works? Or is it well beyond the undergraduate level? (However, being able to learn the method of characteristics on my own has given me confidence that I can indeed learn the theory, provided I work hard)

Comment: For both linear and non-linear first order equations you can take a look at Partial Differential Equations by Fritz John.

Comment: I already checked that book out. It doesn't seem to cover much of nonlinear PDEs, and definitely doesn't mention any of the methods in the link I mentioned. Thanks though!

Comment: You omit one important item from your posting. What is your background in mathematics? Have you had a rigorous analysis course? Multivariable analysis? The link you've posted seems to be more of a numerical approach for engineering.

Comment: "Mathematical Methods In The Physical Sciences" - Mary Boas, is my go-to book for many problems and the partial differentiation content is clear and easy to understand. Being a book aimed at science students, every chapter is full of applied examples.

Comment: I'm sorry about that! No, I haven't had any rigorous proof-based courses so far. I've taken single-variable and multivariable calculus, and a course on ODEs. But I did try to see the 'why' behind most of the proofs involved on my own, already the proof sketches, though the courses omitted it.

Comment: @Jacobadtr: I've heard good things about Boas's book. Thank you, I shall check it out!